# One user single device login using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, jwt

I am using node js for REST API and mongodb for database. For authentication, I have used token based authentication using JWT. I need to allow users to login to application only single user at a time. When the second user logs into application, the first user needs to be automatically logged out. If using passport-session, how can i implement for API for mobile application.

Comment: where do you save user token in your collection?

Comment: did you mean 1 user at 1 device, same user cant login using another device

Comment: @MuhammadAli once the user logs in token generated is stored in users device storage, should i store it in my database.

Comment: @akshaybagade yeah one user at one device.

Comment: check the token is empty(null) or not before login, if token is not empty(null) then dont allow to login, and token is empty then allow to login, also remove the token while logout,  you should store token to your db